# Call the function n times by passing 1 to n as a parameter with dataframe as the output of the function

Tags: scala, iterator

I have a dataframe and lookup dataframe, I want to join my inputDf with my lookupDf N times by passing N as parameter to the function joinByColumn as N becomes one of the joining condition. Also the output should be combination of inputDf and the selected columns in lookupDf.

I can achieve this by foldLeft function but I want to do it using map or iterator function

```
val result = (0 to n).foldLeft(inputDf) {
case (df, colName) => joinByColumn(colName.toString(), df).toDF()
}

def joinByColumn( value: String, inputDf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
val lookupDF=  readFromCassandraTableAsDataFrame(sqlContext,"keyspace","table")
inputDf.as("src").join(lookupDF,lookupDF("a").equalTo(inputDf("input_a")) && lookupDF("b").equalTo((value.toInt + 1).toString) ], "left")
.select("src.*", "c")
.withColumnRenamed("c", value)
}
```

I want the output to be datframe with all the joined columns.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `foldLeft` which is in fact suitable in this use case – transforming an immutable dataframe successively by means of a binary operator function?

Comment: Its a streaming spark job in my case and it is causing job go out of memory. Read in couple of articles that foldLeft can cause that. So I wanted to come up with something else.